# What does mbstring.strict_detection do?

Tags: php, configuration, mbstring

The mbstring PHP module has a `strict_detection` setting, [documented here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mbstring.configuration.php#ini.mbstring.strict-detection). Unfortunately, the manual is completely useless; it only says that this option *"enables the strict encoding detection"*.

I did a few tests and could not find how any of the mbstring functions are affected by this. [`mb_check_encoding()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mb-check-encoding.php) and [`mb_detect_encoding()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mb-detect-encoding.php) give exactly the same result for both valid and invalid UTF-8 input.

(edit:) The `mbstring.strict_detection` option was added in PHP 5.1.2.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Without the *strict* parameter being set, the encoding detection is faster but will not be as accurate. For example, if you had a UTF-8 string with partial UTF-8 sequence like this:

```
$s = "H\xC3\xA9ll\xC3";
$encoding = mb_detect_encoding($s, mb_detect_order(), false);
```

The result of the `mb_detect_encoding` call would still be "UTF-8" even though it's not valid UTF-8 (the last character is incomplete).

But if you set the *strict* parameter to true...

```
$s = "H\xC3\xA9ll\xC3";
$encoding = mb_detect_encoding($s, mb_detect_order(), true);
```

It would perform a more thorough check, and the result of that call would be FALSE.

Comment: That's right, but the setting of `mbstring.strict_detection` doesn't affect that behavior (not even the default value of the $strict parameter).

Comment: It works for me. With `mbstring.strict_detection = On` the default value for the *strict* parameter is true. Note that this is only available since PHP 5.1.2.

Comment: Ah, you're right, it *does* affect `mb_detect_encoding()` if the third parameter is missing. I had an error in my tests; only `mb_check_encoding()` and `mb_convert_encoding()` are unaffected. Thank you.